# c# lock in generic function

Tags: c#, multithreading, generics, locking

I have such a class:

```
public static class CacheManager
{
    static object lockObject = new object();

    static MemcachedClient CacheObject
    {
        get
        {
            if (!MemcachedClient.Exists(Settings.Default
                .CacheInstanceName))
            {
                MemcachedClient.Setup(Settings.Default
                    .CacheInstanceName,
                        new string[] {Settings.Default
                            .CacheHostAddress});
            }
            //
            //
            return MemcachedClient.GetInstance(Settings
                .Default.CacheInstanceName);
        }
    }

    public static List<TData> Get<TData>(string key, Func<List<int>> getListCallback,
        Func<int, TData> getItemCallback) where TData : class
    {
        var result = new List<TData>();
        //
        //
        var list = CacheObject.Get(key);
        if (list == null)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                list = CacheObject.Get(key);
                if (list == null)
                {
                    list = getListCallback();
                    CacheObject.Set(key, list);
                    //
                    //
                    foreach (var id in (List<int>)list)
                    {
                        var item = getItemCallback(id);
                        result.Add(item);
                        CacheObject.Set(string.Concat(key, id), item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var id in (List<int>)list)
            {
                var itemKey = string.Concat(key, id);
                //
                //
                var item = CacheObject.Get(itemKey);
                if (item == null)
                {
                    lock (lockObject)
                    {
                        item = CacheObject.Get(itemKey);
                        if (item == null)
                        {
                            item = getItemCallback(id);
                            CacheObject.Set(itemKey, item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //
                //
                result.Add((TData)item);
            }
        }
        //
        //
        return (List<TData>)result;
    }

    public static void Remove(string key)
    {
        CacheObject.Delete(key);
    }
}
```

it is used in classes-repositories:

```
public class NewsRepository : BaseRepository, IRepository
{

    public List<News> FindAll()
    {
        return CacheManager.Get<News>(key,
            () => clientEntities.News.OrderByDescending(n => n.DateCreated).Select(n => n.NewsId).ToList(),
            (id) => clientEntities.News.Single(n => n.NewsId == id));
    }
}
public class PagesRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public List<Page> FindAll()
    {

        return CacheManager.Get<Page>(key,
            () => clientEntities.Pages.OrderBy(p => p.PageId).Select(p => p.PageId).ToList(),
            (id) => clientEntities.Pages.Single(p => p.PageId == id));
    }
}
```

my question is: for example NewsRepository didn't find news in cache and got the lock and began to load data but at this moment PagesRepository didn't find pages in cache. will PagesRepository's CacheManager be locked by NewsRepository or (I think so) NewsRepository's CacheManager is another static class and its internal locks do not touch PagesRepository's CacheManager?

Comment: Careful with double-check locking. The memory that holds the value that you're checking to be null or not needs to be declared volatile, otherwise the CLR memory model doesn't guarantee that out-of-order memory writes will work correctly. I avoid double-check locks for that reason.

Comment: @RickNZ, you are talking about the following? | var list = CacheObject.Get(key);
        if (list == null)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                list = CacheObject.Get(key);
                if (list == null)
                { ... | Could you describe the problem a bit in detail or give me some links to read about this?

Comment: Yes, that's the code I'm talking about. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A static field of a non-generic type (that is itself not nested in a generic type etc) exists only once, so all the locks will conflict.

If (comments) your aim is to make the lock per-type (from the generic method), then perhaps the best way to do that is:

```
public static class CacheManager {
    static class TypeLock<T> {
        public static readonly object SyncLock = new object();
    }
    ...
    void SomeGenericMethod<TData>(args) {
       ...
       lock(TypeLock<TData>.SyncLock) {
          ...
       }
       ...
    }
}
```

Here, `SyncLock` exists once (and only once) per `T`, so per `TData`. This allows you to keep your existing API (where `CacheManager` is non-generic).

Answer (score 5):

Both will use the same reference to lockObject, and therefore the same lock.

Comment: but if i make all my CacheManager class generic?

Comment: If CacheManager is generic, then there's a lockObject by generic type.
CacheManager<T1>.lockObject != CacheManager<T2>.lockObject

Comment: should the comment above start "If CacheManager is generic, ..." ?

Comment: @MarcGravell uh right, my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. But somehow it looks like I can't edit this comment anymore...